# Command line tool to extract reference

Tags: mendeley

Is there a command line too which can extract a reference from a PDF file, i.e. you have a academic paper and you want to generate a reference for it, by extracting the title, authors, journal, etc. Mendeley can do it, but there's no command line options available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if `pdftk <file> dump_data` would provide the data you want?  Then you could read and format it as you wanted.